# In Clash of clans what do the red or green triangles in margin mean?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've noticed in the left hand margin in my clan tab that there are red or green triangles by players names or sometimes an equal (=) sign...what does this signify?

Answer (score 1):

[image] = The player has opted **out** of clan wars. This is usually selected when they are upgrading heros or won't be able to fully participate.

[image] = The player has opted **in** clans wars.

[image] = The player has moved **up** x position(s) in the clan trophy leader board.  In this example, the player has moved up 1 position.

[image] = The player has moved **down** x position(s) in the clan trophy leader board.  In this example, the player has moved down 1 position.

[image] = The player has **not moved up or down** in the clan trophy leader board.